# Wiki.js Setup page not loaded Properly?

Tags: mongodb, nginx, npm, wiki.js

I'm trying to get into the administration page of Wiki.js but it doesn't seem to be loading properly or is only partially loaded. After finishing the setup process (where the UI of the website was loaded properly):
[Properly loaded wiki.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAeOw.png)
I was redirected to the setup page. When the setup page loaded I was greeted with this:
[White Page, UI not properly loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V759o.png)
Is there a way to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? I had problem like this when deploying on kubernetes, if using separate pods for db and server. Resolved by putting them under one pod. Let me know if you still need help or this info is relevant

Answer (score 0):

I got it... The problem is related to load elements from the node.js server, which doesn't work, because you set the domain to http://localhost

[image]

In the configuration please set the domain to http://YOUR_WIKIJS_IP (not http://localhost !) and it's working!